# Find the number of multiples for a number in range

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a question regarding the [CountDiv](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingRYHD5U-MRA/#task-0) problem in Codility.

The problem given is: *Write a function:*

```
class Solution { public int solution(int A, int B, int K); }
```

*that, given three integers A, B and K, returns the number of integers within the range [A..B] that are divisible by K, i.e.:*

```
{ i : A ≤ i ≤ B, i mod K = 0 }
```

My code:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {        
         int start=0;
         if (B<A || K==0 || K>B )
            return 0;
         else if (K<A)
            start = K * ( A/K +1);
         else if (K<=B)
            start = K;

         return (B-start+1)/K+ 1;
    }
}
```

I don't get why I'm wrong, specially with this test case:

```
extreme_ifempty 
A = 10, B = 10, K in {5,7,20}
WRONG ANSWER 
got 1 expected 0
```

if `K =5` then with `i=10` `A<=i<=B` and `i%k =0` so why should I have 0? [Problem statement](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoV7MXUD-ACC/#task-0).

Comment: hmm, I believe what they means is K is 5 or 7 or 20?

Comment: can you post the original source of the problem? the statement really confused me.

Answer (score 31):

This is the O(1) solution, which passed the [test](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoUZWU5P-BGR/)

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    int b = B/K;
    int a = (A > 0 ? (A - 1)/K: 0);
    if(A == 0){
        b++;
    }
    return b - a;
}
```

Explanation: Number of integer in the range `[1 .. X]` that divisible by `K` is `X/K`. So, within the range `[A .. B]`, the result is `B/K - (A - 1)/K`

In case A is 0, as 0 is divisible by any positive number, we need to count it in.

Comment: Word of comment would help here

Comment: could you explain your solution?

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi some explanation added. This problem is purely math.

Comment: Why do we subtract 1 from A ?

Comment: Cant't we just return (B - A + 1) / K. Since problem doesn't mention anything about negative numbers, adding them to the answer doesn't seem wrong.

Comment: @Isuru It is correct :), I think the formula is just reflected the thinking process I had towards the problems :)

Answer (score 16):

Java solution with O(1) and 100% in codility, adding some test cases with solutions for those who want to try and not see others solutions:

```
  // Test cases
  //  [1,1,1] = 1
  // [0,99,2] = 50
  // [0, 100, 3] = 34  
  // [11,345,17] = 20
  // [10,10,5] = 1
  // [3, 6, 2] = 2
  // [6,11,2] = 3  
  // [16,29,7] = 2
  // [1,2,1] = 2    
public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
   int offsetForLeftRange = 0;
   if ( A % K == 0) { ++offsetForLeftRange; }

   return  (B/K) - (A /K) + offsetForLeftRange;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript solution:
`function solution(a, b, k) {
    return parseInt(b/k) - parseInt(a/k) + (a % k ? 0 : 1);
}`

Comment: Nice, I remember once I was playing with Solutions on a tweet, yours is a good example.

Answer (score 10):

The way to solve this problem is by Prefix Sums as this is part of that section in Codility.

https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/3/

https://codility.com/media/train/3-PrefixSums.pdf

Using this technique one can subtract the count of integers between 0 and A that are divisible by K (A/K+1) from the the count of integers between 0 and B that are divisible by K (B/K+1).

Remember that A is inclusive so if it is divisible then include that as part of the result.

Below is my solution:

```
class Solution {
public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
        int b = (B/K) + 1;  // From 0 to B the integers divisible by K
        int a = (A/K) + 1;  // From 0 to A the integers divisible by K

        if (A%K == 0) { // "A" is inclusive; if divisible by K then
            --a;        //   remove 1 from "a"
        }
        return b-a;     // return integers in range
    }
}
```

Comment: hey my friend, the +1 seems to not be doing anything for both a and b since they cancel each other. At least in javascript I would do `let a = Math.floor(A/K) ;  let b = Math.floor(B/K)`.....So, in java you should be fine with just B/K and A/K. 

`public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
        int b = B/K; 
        int a = A/K; 

        if (A%K == 0) {
            --a;       
        }
        return b-a;     
    }`

Comment: That's because C# and JavaScript handle types and division different. In the C# example above, this is an example integer division.  JS doesn't have integers, instead numbers.

Answer (score 7):

```
return A==B  ? (A%K==0 ? 1:0) : 1+((B-A)/K)*K /K;
```

Well it is a completely illegible oneliner but i posted it just because i can ;-)

complete java code here:

```
package countDiv;

public class Solution {

    /**
     * First observe that
     * <li> the amount of numbers n in [A..B] that are divisible by K  is the same as the amount of numbers n between [0..B-A]
     *      they are not the same numbes of course, but the question is a range question.
     *      Now because we have as a starting point the zero, it saves a lot of code.
     * <li> For that matter, also A=-1000 and B=-100 would work
     * 
     * <li> Next, consider the corner cases.
     *      The case where A==B is a special one: 
     *      there is just one number inside and it either is divisible by K or not, so return a 1 or a 0. 
     * <li> if K==1 then the result is all the numbers between and including the borders.          
     * <p/>
     * So the algorithm simplifies to
     * <pre>
     * int D = B-A; //11-5=6
     * if(D==0) return B%K==0 ? 1:0;
     * int last = (D/K)*K; //6
     * int parts = last/K; //3
     * return 1+parts;//+1 because the left part (the 0) is always divisible by any K>=1.
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param A : A>=1
     * @param B : 1<=A<=B<=2000000000
     * @param K : K>=1  
     */
    private static int countDiv(int A, int B, int K) {      
        return A==B  ? A%K==0 ? 1:0 : 1+((B-A)/K)*K /K; 
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            int a=10;  int b=10; int k=5; int result=1;
            System.out.println( a + "..." + b + "/" + k + " = " +  countDiv(a,b,k)  + (result!=countDiv(a,b,k) ? " WRONG" :" (OK)" ));
        }

        {
            int a=10;  int b=10; int k=7; int result=0;
            System.out.println( a + "..." + b + "/" + k + " = " +  countDiv(a,b,k)  + (result!=countDiv(a,b,k) ? " WRONG" :" (OK)" ));
        }

        {
            int a=6;  int b=11; int k=2; int result=3;
            System.out.println( a + "..." + b + "/" + k + " = " +  countDiv(a,b,k)  + (result!=countDiv(a,b,k) ? " WRONG" :" (OK)" ));
        }

        {
            int a=6;  int b=2000000000; int k=1; int result=b-a+1;
            System.out.println( a + "..." + b + "/" + k + " = " +  countDiv(a,b,k)  + (result!=countDiv(a,b,k) ? " WRONG" :" (OK)" ));
        }
    }
}//~countDiv
```

Comment: Nice explanation but it's not 100% correct. Scores 75% of correctness

Answer (score 3):

I think the answers above don't provide enough logical explanation to why each solution works (the math behind the solution) so I am posting my [solution](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training7ETKHU-H5C/) here.

The idea is to use the [arithmetic sequence](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-arithmetic.html) here. If we have first divisible number (>= A) and last divisible number (<= B) we have an arithmetic sequence with distance K. Now all we have to do is find the total number of terms in the range [newA, newB] which are total divisible numbers in range [newA, newB]

```
first term (a1) = newA
last/n-th term (an) = newB
distance (d) = K
Sn = a1 + (a1+K) + (a1 + 2k) + (a1 + 3k) + ... + (a1 + (n-1)K)

`n` in the above equation is what we are interested in finding. We know that

n-th term = an = a1 + (n-1)K 
as an = newB, a1 = newA so
newB = newA + (n-1)K
newB = newA + nK - K
nK = newB - newA + K
n = (newB - newA + K) / K
```

Now that we have above formula so just apply it in code.

```
fun countDiv(A: Int, B: Int, K: Int): Int {
    //NOTE: each divisible number has to be in range [A, B] and we can not exceed this range
    //find the first divisible (by k) number after A (greater than A but less than B to stay in range)
    var newA = A
    while (newA % K != 0 && newA < B)
        newA++

    //find the first divisible (by k) number before B (less than B but greater than A to stay in range)
    var newB = B
    while (newB % K != 0 && newB > newA)
        newB--

    //now that we have final new range ([newA, newB]), verify that both newA and newB are not equal
    //because in that case there can be only number (newA or newB as both are equal) and we can just check
    //if that number is divisible or not
    if (newA == newB) {
        return (newA % K == 0).toInt()
    }

    //Now that both newA and newB are divisible by K (a complete arithmetic sequence)
    //we can calculate total divisions by using arithmetic sequence with following params
    //a1 = newA, an = newB, d = K
    // we know that n-th term (an) can also be calculated using following formula
    //an = a1 + (n - 1)d
    //n (total terms in sequence with distance d=K) is what we are interested in finding, put all values
    //newB = newA + (n - 1)K
    //re-arrange -> n =  (newB - newA + K) / K
    //Note: convert calculation to Long to avoid integer overflow otherwise result will be incorrect
    val result = ((newB - newA + K.toLong()) / K.toDouble()).toInt()
    return result
}
```

I hope this helps someone. FYI, [codility solution with 100% score](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training7ETKHU-H5C/)

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution in Python:

```
def solution(A, B, K):
    count = 0
    if A % K == 0:
        count += 1
    count += int((B / K) - int(A / K))
    return count
```

explanation:

```
B/K is the total numbers divisible by K [1..B]

A/K is the total numbers divisible by K [1..A]

The subtracts gives the total numbers divisible by K [A..B]

if A%K == 0, then we need to add it as well.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my 100/100 solution:

https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingRQDSFJ-CMR/

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
        return (B==0) ? 1 : B/K + ( (A==0) ? 1 : (-1)*(A-1)/K);
    }
}
```

Key aspects of this solution:

1. If A=1, then the number of divisors are found in B/K.
2. If A=0, then the number of divisors are found in B/K plus 1.
3. If B=0, then there is just one i%K=0, i.e. zero itself.

Comment: I'm not sure you could make this more convoluted if you tried.... (at least in this language)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my simple solution, with 100%
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingQ5XMG7-8UY/

```
public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {

    while (A % K != 0) {
        ++A;
    }
    while (B % K != 0) {
        --B;
    }
    return (B - A) / K + 1;
}
```

Comment: Performance and memory usage could be improved by changing post incement/decrement to pre increment/decrement!

Comment: That's right, @PowerStat, and it can also be improved by another logic as 
 `B = (B/K)*K ` & `int a = (A/K)*K` and `a==A?A=a:A+=K`

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 one line solution with score 100%

```
from math import ceil, floor


def solution(A, B, K):
    return floor(B / K) - ceil(A / K) + 1
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's the quickest solution that runs at O(1). However , why do we need to add 1 at the end?

Answer (score 2):

This works with O(1) [Test link](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingDEV7BM-TEC/)

```
    using System;
    class Solution 
    {
      public int solution(int A, int B, int K) 
      {
       int value = (B/K)-(A/K);
       if(A%K == 0)
       {
        value=value+1;
       }
       return value;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly I believe this is the solution:

```
public static int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    int count = 0;
    if(K == 0) {
        return (-1);
    }
    if(K > B) {
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i = A; i <= B; ++i) {
        if((i % K) == 0) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

returning -1 is due to an illegal operation (division by zero)

Comment: This solution is an overkill, if you look at the problem statement, an O(1) solution exist.

Comment: @PhamTrung you're right I totally didn't see it, and an upvote to you kind sir.

Comment: This will out of runtime. It is linear O(n), the time complexity can be constant O(1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do in your code, but simpler way would be to use modulo operator (%).

```
public int solution(int A, int B, int K) 
{
    int noOfDivisors = 0;
    if(B < A || K == 0 || K > B )
        return 0;
    for(int i = A; i <= B; i++) 
    {
        if((i % K) == 0) 
        {
            noOfDivisors++;
        }
    }
    return noOfDivisors;
}
```

Comment: `if(A > B)` won't enter the `for` loop if it is `true`, but good catch on the `if(k == 0)`

Comment: I thought the starting vars are: **A ≤ i ≤ B** so **A** cannot be greater than **B** thus the condition.

Comment: than you shouldn't return 0, 0 means no divisors in the range. You should return an error code (e.g. -1).

Answer (score 1):

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    int tmp=(A%K==0?1:0);
    int x1=A/K-tmp ;
    int x2=B/K;
    return x2-x1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

100/100 - another variation of the solution, based on Pham Trung's idea

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
         int numOfDivs = A > 0 ? (B / K - ((A - 1) / K)) : ((B / K) + 1);
         return numOfDivs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
        int a = A/K, b = B/K;
        if (A/K == 0)
            b++;
        return b - a;
    }
}
```

This passes the [test](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingB4GZB6-ZVU/).

It's similar to "*how many numbers from 2 to 5*". We all know it's `(5 - 2 + 1)`. The reason we add `1` at the end is that the first number `2` counts.

After `A/K, B/K`, this problem becomes the same one above. Here we need to decide if `A` counts in this problem. Only if `A%K == 0`, it counts then we need to add `1` to the result `b - a` (the same with `b+1`).

Comment: You wrote "Only if A%K == 0", but in your code you write **A/K == 0**. Plus you are not checking if K == 0, which can cause a division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, two lines of Java code.

```
public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    int a = (A == 0) ? -1 : (A - 1) / K;
    return B / K - a;
}
```

The thought is simple.
a refers to how many numbers are divisible in [1..A-1]
B / K refers to how many numbers are divisible in [1..B]
0 is divisible by any integer so if A is 0, you should add one to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution and got 100%

```
public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    int count = B/K - A/K;
    if(A%K == 0) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

1. B/K will give you the total numbers divisible by K [1..B]
2. A/K will give you the total numbers divisible by K [1..A]
3. then subtract, this will give you the total numbers divisible by K [A..B]
4. check A%K == 0, if true, then + 1 to the count

Answer (score 1):

My 100% score solution with one line code in python:

```
def solution(A, B, K):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    return int(B/K) - int(A/K) + (A%K==0)
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Another O(1) solution which got 100% in the test.

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    if (A%K)   
        A = A+ (K-A%K);

    if (A>B)
        return 0;

    return (B-A)/K+1;
}
```

Comment: This gives 100% but doesn't seem to make sense with the following input:
Input: 0, 1000000000, 2000000000
Result: 1 (Should be 0?)

Input: 0, 2000000000, 1000000000
Result: 3 (Should be 2?)

Answer (score 0):

This is my 100/100 solution:

```
public int solution1(int A, int B, int K) {
    return A == 0 ? B / K - A / K + 1 : (B) / K - (A - 1) / K;
}
```

0 is divisible by any integer so if A is 0, you should add one to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the O(1) solution, ( There is no check required for the divisility of `a`)

```
public static int countDiv(int a, int b, int k) {
        double l1 = (double)a / k;
        double l = -1 * Math.floor(-1 * l1);        
        double h1 = (double) b / k; 
        double h =  Math.floor(h1);
        Double diff = h-l+1;
        return diff.intValue();
    }
```

Comment: Why the complete difference in notation?  Notice the other answers?  And this is 4 years after the question was asked and answered.....

Comment: Could you explain me what you want to ask. It is 4 years later since I attempted it in 2018 and was able to solve with different solution. That's why posted it here

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of great answers, but I think this one has some elegance in it, also gives [100% on codility](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingF9NBK7-WZE/).

---

```
public int solution(int a, int b, int k) {
    return Math.floorDiv(b, k) - Math.floorDiv(a-1, k);
}
```

---

Explanation: Number of integers in the range `[1 .. B]` that divisible by `K` is `B/K`. Range `[A .. B]` can be transformed to `[1 .. B]` - `[1 .. A)` (notice that round bracket after A means that A does not belong to that range). That gives as a result `B/K - (A-1)/K`. Math.floorDiv is used to divide numbers and skip remaining decimal parts.

Answer (score 0):

I will show my code in go :)

```
func CountDiv(a int, b int, k int) int {
   count := int(math.Floor(float64(b/k)) - math.Floor(float64(a/k)));
   if (math.Mod(float64(a), float64(k)) == 0) {
      count++
   }

   return count
}
```

The total score is 100%

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still interested in this exercise, I share my Python solution (100% in Codility)

```
def solution(A, B, K):

    if not (B-A)%K:
        res = int((B-A)/K)
    else:
        res = int(B/K) - int(A/K)

    return res + (not A%K)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int divB = B / K;
    int divA = A / K;
    if(A % K != 0) {
        divA++;
    }
    return (divB - divA) + 1;
```

passed 100% in codelity

Answer (score -1):

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K)
{
    // write your code in C++14 (g++ 6.2.0)
    int counter = 0;

    if (A == B)
        A % K == 0 ? counter++ : 0;
    else
    {
        counter = (B - A) / K;

        if (A % K == 0) counter++;
        else if (B % K == 0) counter++;
        else if ((counter*K + K) > A && (counter*K + K) < B) counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: You shoud explain your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Assumptions:
A and B are integers within the range [0..2,000,000,000];
K is an integer within the range [1..2,000,000,000];
A ≤ B.

```
int from = A+(K-A%K)%K;
if (from > B) {
    return 0;
}
return (B-from)/K + 1;
```